# Is my database schema going to work? Tracking git issues

Tags: database, database-design

My boss wants an automated weekly report on how many git issues have been moved to and from various "lanes" (pipelines) on a virtual kanban board. I wrote a quick python script to get that data using Github and Zenhub APIs, and now I'd like to write that data to disk.

My current plan is to run this script once an hour, and write to a transaction table when I see that an issue has changed pipelines. Here's a diagram of my current schema:
[image: db schema]

So my question is, will this schema be able to support a large number of entries in the Transactions table? This will be tracking somewhere between 1,000 - 10,000 issues, with 50 - 1,000 transactions a day.

Some things worth mentioning:

- There can be two or more issues with the same IssueNumber and different repoIDs (issues are assigned a number when opened starting from 1). So I'd like to use both RepoID and IssueNumber as the primary key for Issues table.
- I might have the one-to-many arrows backwards, for example I'm trying to say that one RepoID can correspond to many entries in the Issues table but each entry only corresponds to one RepoID.
- I'm using Postgres

I've never really designed a database before and there aren't really coworkers that can help me, so I would appreciate any advice or criticism on this schema.

Comment: If you are really tracking issues and statuses to that volume buy a product that does it and meets your reporting requirements, in the long run its worth it.

Answer (score 0):

(It's a cool project, of course there are products that you can buy that do it for you.)

---

General suggestions to look for:

- Catching the events of interest (pipeline move for example).
- Process them efficiently and reliably. Currently, you are handling it on your computer and writing it to a file (Is it reliable to your needs ? What will you do when inconsistency will be introduced in such a way ?)

---

From reading your question description (which isn't enough as it's hardly a thorough analysis), your database scheme seems reasonable:

- You should search on (RepoID x IssueID) as you suggested due to the duplication in issue numbers.
- It can handle such load (10-10K issues, 50-1K transactions/day), even if you'll do it naively.

The important question is how this database scheme will help your needs in the creation of automated reports ?
What do you need in your reports, and will you be able to get your data of interest from this scheme simply & efficiently ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'm relieved to hear you think the db can handle that load with a naive implementation.

I don't think my boss knows what he wants in the report. I do know that it needs to have the number of issues that left and entered each pipeline each day (and possibly by hour and week).